# Finding all pairs of non-consecutive number in unsorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of unsorted numbers, need to get all pairs of non-consecutive elements.

```
Input [2,3,4,5,9,8,10,13]
Desired output (2,5)(8,10)(13,13)
```

Explanation:

```
Input = [2,3,4,5,9,8,10,13]
```

if we create sequence in increasing order of given array then it will be:

```
[2,3,4,5,8,9,10,13]
```

now, if break down into groups wheres the sequence get breaks:

```
[2,3,4,5]
[8,9,10]
[13]
```

then, output would be first & last number of the groups, if there is only number in group then it'll be treated as fast & last.

Output:

```
[2,5][8,10][13,13]
```

My workaround :

```
var array = [2,3,4,5,9,8,10,13]
var input = array.sort((a,b)=>{return a-b});
var group = [];
var start = input[0];
for(let i = 0; i<input.length; i++){
    if(input[i+1] - input[i] > 1){
        group.push([start,input[i]])
        start = input[i+1];
    }
}
console.log(group);
```

Output:

```
[ [ 2, 5 ], [ 8, 10 ] ]
```

Comment: Presumably because of the edit showing your attempt, there are several votes to reopen this question.  I would add my own if you also added some more explanation.  I don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - as can see in `input/desired output` need to find out pair of numbers, which is non-consecutive sequence, updating the question as well.

Comment: will the input array ever contain duplicate values?

Comment: @Thankyou - yes, input is an array of unsorted numbers that contains duplicate as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### My approach

Here's an implementation that does exactly the steps you suggest above.  First we `sort` numerically.  Then we use `reduce` to break this down into groups of consecutive numbers.  Then we `map` the arrays in that result to take the first and last values.

Because we will need it several times, we write a simple helper function, `last` to get the final element in an array.

```js
const last = (xs) => 
  xs [xs .length - 1]

const nonConsecutives = (ns) =>
  [...ns] 
    .sort ((a, b) => a - b) 
    .reduce (
      (r, n, i) => (i == 0 || n > last (last (r)) + 1)
        ? r .concat ([[n]])
        : r .slice (0, -1) .concat ([last (r) .concat (n)]),
      []
    ) 
    .map (ns => [ns [0], last (ns)])


console .log (
  nonConsecutives ([2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 10, 13])
)
```

##### Fixing your approach

If you're more wondering where your approach went wrong, the problem is at the boundaries (as is so often true in much programming!)  The line `if (input [i + 1] - input [i] > 1)` will have an issue at the last `i`, since there will be no `input [i + 1]`.  Similarly, you don't want to perform this update `start = input [i + 1]` on the first iteration.

This similar version seems to work.  We test between the current index and the previous one.  (We also add a pre-check that the current index is `0`, which is not technically necessary, since the `input [i] - input [i - 1]` would yield `input [i] - undefined`, which is `NaN`, and `NaN > 1` is false, so we couldn't enter the body of the `if` statement.  But, while not technically necessary, it's much cleaner.)  We don't push a new group on the first index, but after the loop is completed we push a final group.

Here's an implementation:

```js
const array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 10, 13]
const input = array .sort ((a, b) => a - b)
const group = []
let start = input [0]
for (let i = 0; i < input .length; i++){
    if (i == 0 || input [i] - input [i - 1] > 1) {
        if  (i > 0) {
          group .push ([start, input [i - 1]])
        }
        start = input [i]
    }
}
group .push ([start, input [input .length - 1]])

console.log(group);
```

##### Differences

The differences in approaches here is substantial.  Of course one is that I wrap my manipulation in a function.  Those who prefer functional programming will almost always do this.  Another is that I build mine as a series of distinct transformations.  I would usually do this more explicitly (more on that below) but it's still pretty clear here: first we sort, then we group, then we capture the endpoints.  This is often not the most efficient method, but it's often the clearest.

The biggest difference is that in my version, we don't mutate any variables along the way, only creating new ones.  (That's even true inside the `reduce` callback, although sometimes performance concerns will make me choose otherwise here.)  This is a central tenet of functional programming: never mutate input data.

##### Using Ramda

I'm one of the founders of the [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com) functional programming library.  It has a number of useful helper functions; and it's designed around the notion of pipelines of simple transformation, none of which mutate their data.  In Ramda, we might write this more simply:

```js
const {pipe, sortBy, identity, groupWith, map, juxt, head, last} = R

const nonConsecutives = pipe (
  sortBy (identity),
  groupWith ((a, b) => b - a <= 1),
  map (juxt ([head, last]))
)

console .log (
  nonConsecutives ([2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 8, 10, 13])
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

I won't get into the details of how this works.  And I'm not trying to sell Ramda.  But the idea is that breaking problems down into smaller problems can make for very clean code.  If you can capture those smaller parts in pure functions, you are well on your way to doing functional programming.

Comment: perfect answer. i really can't find any holes to poke in this. and the ramda solution is such a flex, what a thing of beauty.